# Spring @Component with external beans

Tags: java, spring

I have to use third party cache in my project and this is my class

```
import com.cgm.life.common.cdi.cache.CacheName;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    @CacheName("journeyID")
    private ConcurrentMap<String, String> journeyIdMap;

    //other codes
}
```

The third party class looks like ( not a Spring project)

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
@Qualifier
public @interface CacheName {
    ....
}
```

But `MyClass` is failing to compile with

> cannot find bean with qualifier journeyID

Of course, if I remove the `@Component` annonation from my class, there is no issue. Is there any way to resolve it ? I can't change the third party stuff and I don't want to use any xml in my project. Maybe something can be done with `@PostConstruct` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: EnableCaching  in main class

Comment: and use bean annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration bean, where you create a bean from your 3rd party class.

This way, you'll have it as a bean in the spring bean container, and you'll be able to wire it into your `MyClass`.

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public CacheName journeyID() {
    return new CacheName() etc..    
  }

}
```

Comment: You mean creating a class ( like CacheName) for each cache ?